# Eliminar ceros internos en una cadena regex

Tags: regex

Como sería una expresión regular para eliminar los ceros en negrita. La cadena siempre empieza por 1 o más letras a continuación una cantidad de ceros y a continuación una cadena numérica que acaba con una letra. Aqui unos ejemplos

ZX**0000**460750W --> ZX56750W

X**00000**460750W --> X460750W

Y**000**43600750W --> Y43600750W

YB**0**4360075430W --> YB4360075430W

Comment: cual es la regla a seguir? Hablas de "ceros internos" pero en tu ejemplo borras 0 que están al principio de la cadena... Y luego hay otros ceros que se quedan.. podrías explicar mejor que intentas conseguir? Aquí tienes una rejex que borra los 0 pero no es lo que buscas por el mensaje: `echo "ZX0000460750W" | sed 's/0//g'`

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la cadena empieza por una o varias letras (ZX en el ejmplo) y luego le siguen 1 o varios ceros(00000) y a continuación una cadena numérica que puede contener ceros o no y acabar o no con una letra(460750W). También hay veces que pueden haber 1 o mas ceros al principo de la cadena (esos serían los más sencillos de eliminar)

Comment: Mi recomendación sería: Actualiza la pregunta, borra la parte de los ceros al principio si sabes como resolverlo, para hacer mas simple la pregunta. Y explica estas reglas. Empieza siempre por una cantidad indeterminada de letras, seguido por 1 o varios ceros y a continuación una cadena numérica y acaba con letra, pero quiero borrar solo los ceros que están entre las primeras letras y el siguiente número que no sea un 0. Eso es mucho más fácil de entender.

Comment: Gracias. Voy a editar esta pregunta con lo que me has dicho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta los comentarios. La regex que buscas es la siguiente: `^0*?([A-Za-z]+)0*(\w+)$`

Las regex en general son un concepto complicado y hay que tener en cuenta que cada motor las ejecuta de una forma un poco distinta.. te recomiendo que uses una página como [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) para entender y jugar con ellas

Esa regex generará 2 capture group, que se usan como `$1` y `$2` en la herramienta.

Vamos a diseccionar la regex un poco para entenderla

```
^ // Significa "empieza por" por lo que si tu valor tiene algo antes no hará match

0*? // Aquí están pasando 2 cosas, primero le digo que haga match con todos los 0 existentes. Y el interrogante le dice que puede que esos cero no existan

( // Esto inicia un capture group. Lo cual significa que todo lo que haga match con la regla interior se guardará en la variable `$1`

 [A-Za-z]+  // `[]` sirve para declarar un character set. En este caso le damos una lista de valores que pueden hacer match en cualquier orden. A-Z es un rango y como imaginarás son todas las letras mayúsculas y luego a-z por lo cual estamos haciendo match con cualquier letra ASCII no utf-8. Por último el + indica que capture tantas como pueda. Sin el + solo capturaría una de ellas
)
 0* // Aquí le decimos que haga match con cualquier 0, nótese que no hacemos un capture group de esta parte porque la vamos a descartar

 (\w+) // Otro capture group y en este caso le pasamos un "character class" que no es mas que una forma rápida de declarar un character set concreto. En este caso \w es lo mismo que [A-Za-z0-9] por lo cual cualquier letra y número
 $  // Y el dolar marca el final de la cadena. Por lo que si hubiese espacios o alguna otra cosa no hará match
```

Lo importante a entender es que hacemos una regex que haga un match sobre el valor completo. Y luego hacemos capture groups de las partes que nos queremos quedar, ignorando las partes que vamos a quitar. Regex no hace remplazos per se pero podemos usar sus capture groups para quedarnos con lo que nos interesa.

Con lo cual tus ejemplos quedarían así:

```
$1        $2
(ZX)0000(460750W)
(X)00000(460750W)
(Y)000(43600750W)
(YB)0(4360075430W)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias crack